# calculate Value at Risk in a data frame

Tags: r, time-series

My data set has 1000s hedge fund returns for 140 months and I was trying to calculate Value at Risk (VaR) suing command VaR in PerformanceAnalytics package. However, I have come up with many questions when using this function. I have created a sample data frame to show my problem.

```
df=data.frame(matrix(rnorm(24),nrow=8))
df$X1<-c('2007-01','2007-02','2007-03','2007-04','2007-05','2007-06','2007-07','2007-08')
df[2,2]<-NA
df[2,3]<-NA
df[1,3]<-NA
df
```

I got a data frame:

```
           X1         X2          X3
    1 2007-01 -1.4420195          NA
    2 2007-02         NA          NA
    3 2007-03 -0.4503824 -0.78506597
    4 2007-04  1.4083746  0.02095307
    5 2007-05  0.9636549  0.19584430
    6 2007-06  1.1935281 -0.14175623
    7 2007-07 -0.3986336  1.58128683
    8 2007-08  0.8211377 -1.13347168
```

I then run

```
apply(df,2,FUN=VaR, na.rm=TRUE)
```

and received a warning message:

> The data cannot be converted into a time series.  If you are trying to pass in names from a data object with one column, you should use the form 'data[rows, columns, drop = FALSE]'.  Rownames should have standard date formats, such as '1985-03-15'.

I have tried to convert my data frame into combination of time series using `zoo()` but it didn't help. Can someone help to figure out what should I do now?

Comment: @LittleBobbyTables: Why do you keep reverting my tag suggestions? I do believe that it makes it easier to access certain questions. What is wrong with the tag [risk-management] or [finance] for certain posts where **Value at Risk** occurs?

Comment: @B--rian - they're meta tags, as described here:  https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/08/07/the-death-of-meta-tags/.  `If the tag can’t work as the only tag on a question, it’s probably a meta-tag`  The tag only enhances other tags, but would be off-topic as a stand-alone tag.  Also, although not the case here, you have a bad habit of editing tags into off-topic questions (although you do make it easier to find off-topic questions).  There's only four questions left with the [risk-management] tag, as it's being cleaned up.  You can suggest a [value-at-risk] tag instead, since that's an actual func

Comment: @LittleBobbyTables Understood, but I would not have minded if you told me that earlier. But you are also saying, that in a way, my work was actually helpful to identify off-topic questions. :-)

Answer (score 1):

@user2893255, you should convert your data frame into an xts-object before using the apply function:

```
df.xts <- as.xts(df[,2:3],order.by=as.Date(df$X1,"%Y-%m"))
```

and then

```
apply(df.xts,2,FUN=VaR, na.rm=TRUE)
```

gives you the result without warnings or error messages.

Answer (score 0):

Try dropping the `Date` column:

```
 apply(df[,-1L], 2, FUN=VaR, na.rm=TRUE)
```

Comment: Thanks for giving the answer but it seems the problem cannot be fixed by dropping the date column. The warning message is still there.